# How is the beautiful way to reference something in an array returned by a function?

Tags: php

I am trying to reference something inside an array i get from a function.

Lets say I have a collection named `$myArrays` and when i call `$myArrays->first();` I will get an array.

Now when I try to get the first element in my array with `$myArrays->first()[0]` this doesn't work. Why is that so and is there a way to use it in a similar way?

Regards, Senad

Comment: how is "beautiful" related to your question ?

Comment: Give him a break.  He's trying to write elegant/correct code.  English may not be his first language, but he *is* making an effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are not using [PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php):

> Function array dereferencing has been added, e.g. foo()[0]

You need a temporary variable:

```
$first = $myArrays->first();
$first[0]
```

And no, you cannot "trick" PHP this way either:

```
($myArray->first())[0]
```

Comment: thanks for that answer! :) I'm currently using the trick with the temporary variable... Nice to see that PHP is evolving ;)

Comment: You're welcome. Fluffeh: thanks, it's not that special though ;)